# Boundary test with Raven Db

Tags: c#, testing, asp.net-web-api, ravendb

I am building a system using Web API and Raven DB.

I am writing integration tests against the external boundary of this system.

```
public void GetAfterPostingPollReturnsPoll()
{
    using (var client = HttpClientFactory.Create())
    {
        var poll = new
        {
            Question = "What is the answer?",
            Options = new[] { "Yes", "No", "Maybe" }
        };
        var postResponse = client.PostAsJsonAsync("", poll).Result;
        var pollLocation = postResponse.Headers.Location;
        var getResponse = client.GetAsync(pollLocation).Result;
        var actual = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Poll>(
            getResponse.Content
                .ReadAsStringAsync()
                .Result);
        Assert.Equal(poll.Question, actual.Question);
        Assert.Equal(poll.Options, actual.Options);
    }
}
```

When I submit an entry, the `Controller` interacts with a `DocumentStore` because that is how it works in production.

The trouble I am having is that the data produced in the test is never cleaned up.

Based on what I have been reading, I should use the `EmbeddableDocumentStore` for the purposes of my acceptance tests.

How might I use the `DocumentStore` normally but the `EmbeddableDocumentStore` when executing boundary tests like this one?

Answer (score 1):

How do you "interact with DocumentStore" in your controller? The controller really only need to "interact" with the IDocumentSession that could be injected by the WebAPI infrastructure and in your integration test you register IDocumentStore to be implemented by EmbeddableDocumentStore (providing you use some kind of IoC container).